# Silly WebSphere MQ questions

Tags: queue, ibm-mq

I have two very basic questions on WebSphere MQ - given that I had been kind of administrating it for past few months I tend to think that these are silly questions

1. Is there a way to "deactivate" a
   queue ? (for example through a
   runmqsc command or through the
   explorer interface) - I think not. I
   think what I can do is just delete
   it.
2. What will happen if I create a
   remote queue definition if the real
   remote queue is not in place? Will
   it cause any issues on the queue
   manager? - I think not. I think all
   I will have are error messages in
   the logs.

Please let me know your thoughts.
Thanks!

Comment: how about accept, vote and then vote on the comment too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1 Is there a way to "deactivate" a
>   queue?

Yes.  You can change the queue attributes like so:
`ALTER Q(QUEUE_NAME) PUT(DISABLED) GET(DISABLED)`

Any connected applications will receive a return code on the next API call telling them that the queue is no longer available for PUT/GET.  If these are well-behaved programs they will then report the error and either end or go into a retry loop.

> 2 What will happen if I create a
>   remote queue definition if the real
>   remote queue is not in place?

The QRemote definition will resolve to a transmit queue.  If the message can successfully be placed there your application will receive a return code of zero.  (Any unsuccessful PUT will be due to hitting MAXDEPTH or other local problem not connected to the fact that the remote definition does not exist.)

The problem will be visible when the channel tries to deliver the message.  If the remote QMgr has a Dead Letter Queue, the message will go there.  If not, it will be backed out onto the local XMitQ and the channel will stop.